# we have g_errbuf := SQLERRM in the exception blocks . What is assigned to variable g_errbuf here?

Tags: sql, debugging, plsql, plsql-package

```
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      g_errbuf  := SQLERRM;
      g_retcode := 2;
      write_log('Y',
                to_char(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') || ' - ' ||
                'Data Error happened having Batch ID = ' || p_batch_id ||
                ' and invoice_ulid = ' || l_process_data_rec_type.invoice_ulid);
      write_log('Y',
                to_char(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') || ' - ' || 'Error ' ||
                l_procedure_name || ' : ' || g_errbuf);
      IF c_get_ap%ISOPEN
      THEN
        CLOSE c_get_ap;
      END IF;
```

Comment: Please put the detailed question in the question itself, not only in the title

Answer (score 1):

No better place to start the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-7E0CDD98-D31C-4745-B819-B5C5E1DF90A8). If the exception is thrown, `SQLERRM` will contain the error message.

Example:

```
set serveroutput on size 999999
DECLARE
  l_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_num := 'x';
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
END;
/
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
```

So in your code, the variable `g_errbuf` will contain the error message of the statement that is erroring out.